# Error in Deploying two React apps in nginx

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, nginx, npm, amazon-ec2

Trying to Deploy two React apps

```sh
server {
listen 80;

#  server_name IPAddress;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/Static.com.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/Static.com.error.log;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
   location /elderly/ {
#    rewrite ^/codify(.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
       #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

[www.IPadress.com](http://www.IPadress.com) is working fine but when I open the [www.IPadress.com/elderly](http://www.IPadress.com/elderly) it is not working.

Comment: "it is not working" could mean a lot of different things. Can you show an example of the failure mode with as much detail as possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `PUBLIC_URL` field in you `.env` file:

```
PUBLIC_URL=/elderly
```